# Is it possible to make a dynamic mix of ListView and TextView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I tried to found a method, but no results. I want a ListView like below, and when I click on an element, like "Word", it'll be like this picture :

[image: And the result I want]

Is it possible ?

Comment: Surely possible , For first Pic, you need to create custom adapter by extending baseAdapter class

Comment: Yep it is easy to make, but for the second picture ? (i changed my post because it is not clear :/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described is what an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) does.
Basically it's like a listview so you'll still have to create your own adapter, but it lets you click a row to inflate a bigger item that you can then stuff your text into.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating your own class that extends `ArrayAdapter` or `BaseAdapter`.  Then you can make use of the `getView()` method that gets called every time the screen gets redrawn for the user.  You can then design multiple views for each selection and choose which one to display in the `getView()` function.  So when the user selects an item, you set a flag in your custom class, and then `notifyDataSetChanged()` and you're good to go!

Comment: This is definitely the best/easiest way to do it.   For more information on how to make your own lists with ListView and ArrayAdapter, check out this link: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: Too cumbersome. `ExpandableListView` is made for this very purpose, as mentioned in Frank's answer.